# How to us an aggregated value in the where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a problem with this part using Postgresql 9.4 where I need that the program only shows `sum(v.price) > 1000` but if I put `total > 1000` in where conditions says me that total doesn't exists and doesn't let me put `sum(v.price)` because it's not possible to do this kind of operations in this section.

The creation tables are:

```
  CREATE TABLE PATIENT
  (
    Pat_Number  INTEGER,
    Name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Address     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_PATIENT PRIMARY KEY (Pat_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE VISIT
(
    Doc_Number    INTEGER,
    Pat_Number    INTEGER,
    Visit_Date    DATE,
    Price           DECIMAL(7,2),
     Turn               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Visit_pk PRIMARY KEY (Doc_Number, Pat_Number, Visit_Date),
    CONSTRAINT Visit_Doctor_fk FOREIGN KEY (Doc_Number) REFERENCES DOCTOR(Doc_Number),
    CONSTRAINT Visit_PATIENT_fk FOREIGN KEY (Pat_Number) REFERENCES PATIENT(Pat_Number)
);
```

This is the statement where I have problems:

```
 SELECT 
     p.name, p.address, p.city, sum(v.price) as total
 FROM 
     VISIT v 
 JOIN 
     PATIENT p ON p.Pat_Number = v.Pat_Number
 WHERE 
     Date(Visit_Date) < '01/01/2012'      
 GROUP BY
     p.name, p.address, p.city, p.Pat_Number, v.Pat_Number
 ORDER BY 
     total DESC;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Having sum(v.price) > 1000` after `group by`:

```
SELECT 
     p.name, p.address, p.city, sum(v.price) as total
 FROM 
     VISIT v 
 JOIN 
     PATIENT p ON p.Pat_Number = v.Pat_Number
 WHERE 
     Date(Visit_Date) < '01/01/2012'      
 GROUP BY
     p.name, p.address, p.city, p.Pat_Number, v.Pat_Number
 HAVING SUM(v.price) > 1000
 ORDER BY 
     total DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in the `WHERE` part of the query apply at each individual row. You can't use aggregate functions there. There is a similar functionality for groups called `HAVING`. `HAVING` is like `WHERE`, but the conditions are applied per group. So adding `HAVING sum(v.price) > 1000` to the query will filter only those groups, where the sum of price is above 1000.

Answer (score 0):

with a group by we usually use a having clause.  try this:

```
 SELECT p.name, p.address, p.city, sum(v.price) as total
 FROM VISIT v join PATIENT p on  p.Pat_Number = v.Pat_Number
 where Date(Visit_Date)<'01/01/2012'      
 group by p.name, p.address, p.city, p.Pat_Number, v.Pat_Number
 having sum(v.price) > 1000
order by total DESC;
```

let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try having clause for checking sum(v.price)>1000. because here sum is aggregative function on group by clause. so for comparing "sum(v.price)", you should use having clause. so use this sql command

```
SELECT p.name, p.address, p.city, sum(v.price) as total
 FROM VISIT v join PATIENT p on  p.Pat_Number = v.Pat_Number
 where Date(Visit_Date)<'01/01/2012'      
 group by p.name, p.address, p.city, p.Pat_Number, v.Pat_Number
 having sum(v.price) > 1000
 order by total DESC;
```

and if you want more information about having clause then  visit w3schools.com nd see  sql section.